# Google Cloud Storageで定期的にStandardのバケットからNearlineにアーカイブしたい

Tags: python, google-cloud

Object Lifecycle Managementを利用して一定期間経過したファイルを削除することは可能ですが、Standardのバケットで保管していたものをNearlineの方に移してやるようなことは自分でcpやmvするしかないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

転送機能があるので、Standardバケットを転送元として、転送先をNearlineにして、フィルタで一定時間以上最終更新日時が経過したもの、にしたら出来そうに思われますよ。